# Exponentiation confusion for complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

For real numbers, $(a^b)^c$=$(a^{bc})$, and (I think) this generally seems to hold true for complex numbers.
But consider something like this:

$(e^{i2\pi})^c=1^c=1$

For any c. But if c is arbitrary, then $e^{i2\pi c}$ obviously doesn't have to be 1.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: You're not getting anything wrong. It's simply the case that $(a^b)^c$ does not necessarily equal $a^{bc}$ for complex numbers. To learn more about these issues, some useful keywords are "principal value" and "multivalued function". Essentially, the exponential function is not injective in the complex plane, which is what causes the difficulties.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp Do you know what (if any) conditions would make the equality true? I know generally about multivalued functions and principle values and such, but I also know that I have seen certain physics problems solved using this equality seemingly without worry, which makes me think there is some fairly simple ways to know when it is an issue.